# Sprites with same name

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

Hey I am trying to move some sprites at the same time, they are all the same type of sprite.So I just used a for loop to add the sprite in the game  but when I try to move all of the sprites only one moves.

I am trying to simulate running , when the user taps on the Stone the stone will move down and another stone will appear at the top there will be 4 stones so when one goes down another will come on the top and they rest of the stones will move down. I am haveing trouble moveing the stone that comes on the top of the screen that stone doesn't move like the other stones .

Here is some of the Code:

```
self.Stone = [Stone spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(80, 142)];


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];


self.node =[self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([self.node.name isEqualToString:@"stone"]) {
    SKAction *hey = [SKAction moveToY:self.Stone.position.y - 142 duration:1];
    [self runAction:hey];
}
```

They are basically going to be 4 stones on the screen and each time you tap the stones move down.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, it helps if you provide a code example so that we can give you advice specific to your situation.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You have 4 objects (stones) at the top of the view. If you tap 1 object, all 4 are suppose to move down and out of the view and then 4 new stones appear at the top?

Comment: not at the top of the view ok think of it like this there is a 4 by 4 grid on screen 1 stone is at 1 location in each row the second column is where you tap on the stones when you tap the stone all the stones including the one you tapped move down a row the one at the last row gets removed and a new stone is added to the scene at the top row. This would continue untill the player taps the background instead of the stone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the sprite has no real bearing on identification in regards to movement. You can either make one sprite the parent and attach all other sprites as children. Doing this will make all children move when you move the parent or you can dump all the sprites into an array and move each one separately in a loop.

**Updated to include parent/child example**

Below is an example of parent/child. When you tap the screen, the parent sprite is move +10 on x and y. The child will move along with the parent.

Keep in mind that the child position is in relation to the parent and not the view.

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *mainSprite;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        mainSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        mainSprite.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        [self addChild:mainSprite];

         SKSpriteNode *child1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
         child1.position = CGPointMake(40, 40);
        [mainSprite addChild:child1];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     mainSprite.position = CGPointMake(mainSprite.position.x+10, mainSprite.position.y+10);
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //
}

@end
```

Comment: Also I am not removing the sprites in the code I am letting them go off screen and that seems to remove them. Does that have any thing to do with it?

Comment: To do with what? If a sprite moves off screen it is not "removed". Only issuing the command [spriteName removeFromParent] does that. Do you know how to implement the 2 suggestions I made?

Comment: Yes I tried the array one and it didn't even move anything and the parent one had the same effect as before . The node count goes down when it moves off the screen so i assumed it got removed .

Comment: I added a parent/child code example. The node count you see is for the number of sprites (nodes) which are currently being displayed in the view. If a sprite moves off view, the node count is subtracted by 1 but it does not actually remove the node.

Comment: The reason that your example will not work in my case is that i need only the sprite to move the game will go on forever unless the person clicks on the background it inserts a new sprite each time they click the current sprite . Your example eventually removes the mainSprite from the scene I need the mainSprite to stay stationary and all the other sprites to do something else.

Comment: Well that's not what your initial question was. I don't understand what you mean by "i need only the sprite to move the game will go on forever...". Please edit your question and explain in detail what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yea i made it so that it just reuses the stones . thanks for your help